# echo in laravel can't show if I return redirect()

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I want to show alert in my function create() and then return to another function. But the alert not show

I use echo "alert('DONE')"; but it doesn't work

```
public function create(){
    echo "<script>alert('DONE')</script>";
    return redirect()->route('view');
}
```

I expect the alert show before return to another function

Comment: don't mix-merge bad code with good framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AJAX with JS/JQuery, then in ajax callback you will get some "response" from back-end, which will be a new URL, like this:

```
 // ... your logic
 // here don't need to echo anything
 return route('view'); // from back-end you can just send only the URL
```

And in the client-side you can get that URL and after press OK button in alert window you'll be redirected to retrieved URL, like this:

```
 function (response) { // this is AJAX callback
     alert("DONE!");
     window.location.href = response;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When returning your redirect, you can chain "withSucess" with the argument being your desired success message.

```
return redirect()->route('view')->withSuccess('Done');
```

And then in the blade template file of the route you're redirecting to:

```
@if(!empty($successMessage = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::get('success')))
    <script>
        $(function () {
            @if($successMessage)
                alert('{{ $successMessage }}');
            @endif
        });
    </script>
@endif
```

I hope this helps!